# Target size and input size not matching despite "minibatches" tells otherwise

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm relatively new to Pytorch and have been training an AutoEncoder model on the MNIST data set. Before training the model, I have three dataloaders for training-, validation- and test sets.

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
valid_loader = DataLoader(valid_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# get minibatch
x_train, _ = next(iter(train_loader)) 
x_val, _ = next(iter(valid_loader))
x_test, _ = next(iter(test_loader))
```

The three minibatches have the following sizes:

```
torch.Size([128, 784])
torch.Size([128, 784])
torch.Size([128, 784])
```

However, when I run the training loop (in the validation phase), the shapes of validation data does not match and I get the following error:

*ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([96, 784])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([128, 784])) is deprecated.*

The simple model looks as

```
class AE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,latent_dim):
    super(AE, self).__init__()
    ### Encoder layers
    self.fc_enc1 = nn.Linear(784, 32)
    self.fc_enc2 = nn.Linear(32, 16)
    self.fc_enc3 = nn.Linear(16, latent_dim)
    
    ### Decoder layers
    self.fc_dec1 = nn.Linear(latent_dim, 16)
    self.fc_dec2 = nn.Linear(16,32)
    self.fc_dec3 = nn.Linear(32,784)

def encode(self, x):       
    z = F.relu(self.fc_enc1(x))
    z = F.relu(self.fc_enc2(z))
    z = F.relu(self.fc_enc3(z))
    
    return z

def decode(self, z):    
    xHat = F.relu(self.fc_dec1(z))
    xHat = F.relu(self.fc_dec2(xHat))
    xHat = F.sigmoid(self.fc_dec3(xHat))

    return xHat

def forward(self, x):
    ### Autoencoder returns the reconstruction and latent representation
    z = self.encode(x)
    
    ### decode z
    xHat = self.decode(z)
    return xHat, z
```

The training loop looks as following:

```
AEmodel = AE(latent_dim).to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(AEmodel.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
AEmodel.train()
train_loss = 0
for batch_idx, (data, _) in enumerate(train_loader):
    data = data.float().to(device)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    xHat, z = AEmodel(data)
    loss = loss_function(xHat, data)
    loss.backward()
    train_loss += loss.item()
    optimizer.step()

AEmodel.eval()
valid_loss = 0
with torch.no_grad():
    for i, (data, _) in enumerate(valid_loader):
        data = data.float().to(device)
        valid_loss += loss_function(xHat, data).item()
```

The error occurs in the last line of the above code. I have not been able to figure out, where the reshaping appears, which causes some mismatching. Am I blind and not seeing an obvious mistake??

Answer (score 0):

Intended or not, in your last loop `xHat` is constant, because it is not recomputed. It remains the last `xHat` from your train loop. So you compare `xHat` to `data` but they do not come from the same dataloader (they respectively come from `train_loader` and `valid_loader`), hence there is nothing enforcing them to have the same shape. I believe you want to recompute `xHat` at each iteration if your validation loop.

However, that is not the full explanation, because none of the shapes you pasted was (96, 784). I am quite sure it actually is the shape of `xHat` in your last loop, please just add a print statement there to confirm it. Since it's the last batch of your `train_loader`, its size is not necessarily equal to your batch size. This happens when the size of your dataset is not divisible by your batch size. Please have a look at [the datloader documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), in particular the `drop_last` option.

So either you add `drop_last=True` to your dataloaders (which will make the code run fine, but I am not sure you want it to work like that) or you re-compute `xHat` at each iteration of your validation loop to have a meaningful autoencoder validation loop.